# Installing 32bit gcc on Debian squeeze x64

Tags: linux, 64-bit, debian, debian-squeeze

I need to install the 32bit gcc because i get this error:

> libgcc_s.so.1 must be installed for pthread_cancel to work Aborted

I try this:

```
apt-get install lib32gcc1
```

Does not find the package

I also try this:

```
apt-get install ia32-libs ia32-libs-gtk
```

Does not find either

What I can do?

Comment: Debian buster: 32-bit works with build packages `build-essential gcc-multilib lib32gcc-8-dev` and runtime package `lib32gcc1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not specified the architecture (amd64 or ia64 or any other?)

If you are using amd64, lib32gcc1 exists and contains libgcc_s.so.1. I was able to install it when I tried.

If you are using ia64, you should use ia32-libs-core.

[This link](http://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=libgcc_s.so.1&mode=path&suite=stable&arch=any) can tell the package necessary for your architecture.

Sometimes Debian mirrors lose some packages. You can try to install from main US repositories to see if that's the case.

Comment: oh, sorry, it's amd64

Comment: Then you should install lib32gcc1. If you can not install it, there is something wrong with your package manager or repository you are using. Trying using `http://ftp.us.debian.org` servers to your `/etc/apt/sources.list` (possibly with low priority) and try again.

Answer (score 4):

Since Debian 7 (Wheezy) you can fix this with:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same issue and had some problems getting the 32-bit libs installed on Wheezy 7.6. I finally managed to resolve it by targetting 32-bit libgcc1 explicitly:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libgcc1:i386
```

This will add libgcc_s.so.1 to /usr/lib32/

Answer (score 1):

My issue was with Debian 7.6 (Wheezy),
I looked directly in the package and there is also:

dep: libc6-i386 (>= 2.11) [amd64]
    Embedded GNU C Library: 32-bit shared libraries for AMD64

So I tried to install it first and it worked for me:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install libc6-i386
apt-get install lib32gcc1
```